# O que é Closure Object e como pegar o retorno de função anônima como parâmetro?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, expressões-lambda

Digamos que eu tenha uma *classe*, e nessa *classe* eu tenha um *método*, e em um *parâmetro* desse *método* seja possível usar uma *função anônima* assim:

---

Classe e método:

```
class Classe {
    private $exemplo = [];
    public function add($parametro1, $parametro2){
        $this->exemplo['parametro1'] = $parametro1;
        $this->exemplo['parametro2'] = $parametro2;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
$classe = new Classe;
$classe->add('parâmetro 1 aqui', function(){
    return 'retorno da função anonima para o parâmetro 2';
});
```

---

Se eu der um `print_r()` no *array* `$exemplo` da minha *classe*, o resultado vai ser o seguinte:

```
Array ( [parametro1] => parâmetro 1 aqui [parametro1] => Closure Object ( ) )
```

---

O que é exatamente um `Closure Object` e como posso pegar o que foi retornado nessa *função anônima*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É só chamar essa variável como se fosse uma função:

```
$classe->exemplo['parametro2']();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dUySZr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/biwjttus-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/ClosureObject.php).

Só mudei para `public` para facilitar o exemplo, se quer manter a variável privada, só poderá chamar a função passada dentro da própria classe.

O `Closure Object` é o tipo de dado contido ali, ou seja, é um objeto que contém uma função que potencialmente enclausura variáveis locais de onde ela foi definida.

Comment: Muito bom parabens

Answer (score 5):

No PHP, funções anônimas equivale a instancia da classe chamada de `Closure`.

Por exemplo:

```
$a = function () {};

var_dump($a instanceof Closure); // bool(true)
```

Para pegar o retorno de uma `Closure` é preciso chamá-la.

No caso do nosso exemplo acima, basta apenas chamar assim:

```
$a();
```

No caso de você atribuir uma `Closure` a uma propriedade, você não poderá chamá-la dessa maneira destacada acima. Deverá usar uma função:

```
call_user_func($this->closure, $parametro);
```

Ou usar o método da `Closure` chamado `__invoke`.

```
 $this->closure->__invoke($parametro);
```

Veja no Manual e perceberá que a `Closure`, por ser um objeto, possui alguns métodos específicos, que podem mudar seu comportamento.