# Como saber a diferença entre construção de linguagem e função no PHP?

Tags: php, funções, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Como identificar e qual a diferença de uma construção de linguagem para uma função?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Verificando com `function_exists`:

O PHP tem uma função adequada para isto, que retorna verdadeiro para funções, mas retorna falso para construções como `require`, etc.:

```
bool function_exists ( string $function_name )
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/N0MXrO)**.

Manual: **[function_exists](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.function-exists.php)**.

### Listando com `get_defined_functions`:

Esta função já traz a lista todas de funções definidas de uma vez só

```
array get_defined_functions ([ bool $exclude_disabled = FALSE ] )
```

E para complementar, esta lista as constantes definidas e seus valores:

```
array get_defined_constants ([ mixed $categorize ] )
```

Veja ambas funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/7zwxTi)**.

Manual: **[get_defined_functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-defined-functions.php)** e **[get_defined_constants](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-defined-constants.php)**.

Agora, se for para verificar no dia-a-dia ao programar, só lendo no manual, [que tem uma lista de *keywords*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.keywords.php) ou olhando o fonte, visto que em PHP as coisas foram meio que "implementadas a olho". Não compensaria você fazer um fonte para testar cada uma (a não ser que gere uma pequena ferramenta com um form, para consultar o `function_exists` a qualquer momento)

Answer (score 7):

Pergunta já respondida pelo Bacco, vou colocar algo mais teórico.

PHP é uma linguagem um pouco irregular, criada por [quem admite ter feito isso sem saber](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf). Aparentemente não havia o entendimento sobre o que é cada coisa e foram criados comandos ou outras formas na linguagem que na verdade deveriam ser funções.

Claro que eventualmente pode ser útil ter uma construção para evitar por exemplo, não usar parênteses, mas seria possível padronizar isso. Geralmente não é necessário e a adoção de uma construção é mais por não ter a criatividade de ter uma solução mais universal. Também pode ser outros motivos que aquilo age de forma especial ou ainda sem motivo algum, quem criou achou melhor fazer assim por gosto, ou esqueceu de como se fazia antes, e aí fica inconsistente.

Por que o `echo` precisa ser uma construção? Só porque pode não usar parênteses.

Em alguns casos pode ser por causa de performance, mas hoje isso faz menos sentido. Uma construção tem ganho porque é escrita em C, é otimizada para evitar algum custo indesejado e desnecessário e porque não tem o custo de mapear, mas otimizações podem dar conta disto.

Outro motivo é que algumas verificações podem ser feitas antes de executar quando tem uma construção, a função, especialmente em PHP, tende a gerar erro só na execução.

A construção se difere por obrigar o compilador a entendê-la e saber o que fazer, é uma peça de Lego especial.

[image: Peças Lego (blocos de construção) diversos formatos]

Enquanto que a função é algo padronizado e o compilador (ou interpretador, que seja) só precisa saber que é uma função e ela precisa existir com aquele nome, é uma peça de Lego normal.

[image: Peça Lego (blocos de construção) padrão]

Quando tem a construção o compilador precisa previamente ser desenvolvido para entender cada parte do que será permitido ali, tanto em sintaxe quanto semântica. A função é só algo que será delegado para outra parte do código eventualmente passando argumentos de uma forma bem regular e talvez devolva um resultado.

A função nem precisa ser da linguagem, não faz diferença ser interna do PHP, ou sua, ou de uma biblioteca. Claro, as internas podem ter mais performance porque ela pode ser de fato uma função C exposta ao PHP, mas você nem precisa saber disto. Mesmo funções C custam um pouco mais caro do que se fosse C puro porque precisa de uma mapeamento.

Quando tem uma função ela é igual uma variável, de fato o nome da variável e o nome da função são chamados identificadores, não tem diferença. É que o nome da função é como se fosse uma variável de um tipo especial que permite que você a chame e execute um código. Versões mais recentes do PHP permite que ela seja até mesmo passada entre variáveis normais, o que é chamado de função anônima e pode ser expressada através de uma *lambda* e até mesmo conter um mecanismo de [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99545/101).

Uma construção de linguagem não pode fazer isso. Nem mesmo um operador que é muito parecido com uma função e internamente pode até ser uma função, não pode ser usada desta forma.

Uma coisa que poucos sabem é que é possível você criar funções em C e expor para seu código PHP, só não é a linguagem mais fácil para fazer isto.

Claro que existem casos que é mais complicado algo ser tratado como função, inclusive pode passar a ideia errada, ou ter ineficiências, por isso que nenhuma linguagem *mainstream* tem o `if` por exemplo, como uma função.

Uma coisa que eu sempre falo é que o programador só aprende programar mesmo quando ele entende tudo o que está ocorrendo no código dele, que ele sabe até quando usar um espaço em branco ou não, mesmo quando ele é opcional. Um exemplo é esse, você pode usar:

```
if(condicao)
```

Mas isso parece uma função, já usando:

```
if (condicao)
```

Fica mais claro que é uma construção de linguagem que tem uma expressão circundada por parênteses, já que eles também são usados como indicador de argumentos em funções, mesmo que seja zero, ou para agrupar sub-expressões. Sendo ambíguo melhor escrever de forma que deixe claro qual é a intenção.

Muitas vezes quando parece uma função, mas é uma construção de linguagem, chamamos de *built-in function*. E ela pode ser manipulada internamente através da função [`override_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) ou [`rename-function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) e mudar o comportamento ou nome. Mas só use se souber muito o que está fazendo.

Então como o Bacco falou, só consultando o manual pra aprender o que é cada coisa, e eventualmente pode verificar em tempo de execução se é uma função, mas não faça isto em código normal em produção, esta é uma forma avançada para montar execuções que você não sabe o que é até o código executar. Se for fazê-lo tenha certeza que já é muito experiente, porque muita coisa pode dar errada se começar tentar executar código que não tem controle durante o desenvolvimento.